# Kaplan-Meier Estimate with no censoring

Tags: self-study, survival, censoring, kaplan-meier

Let $T_i$ is the survival time for individual $i$ $(i=1,2,\ldots, n)$ and $C_i$ be the time to censoring. Let $U_i=\min(T_i,C_i)$. And $\hat S(U_i)$ is the Kaplan-Meier estimator for the censoring distribution. Suppose $R_i$ and $Z_i$ are two indicator functions. Also, $p$ is a probability. Consider the following estimator of cumulative distribution function:

$$\hat F(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{I(T_i<C_i)(1-R_i+R_iZ_i/p)I(U_i\le t)}{\hat S(U_i)},$$
where $I(.)$ is an indicator function.

Now it is written that, with no censoring $\hat F(t)$ becomes

$$\hat F(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i+R_iZ_i/p)I(T_i\le t).$$

I understand that if there is no censoring, then $I(T_i<C_i)=1$, that is, we will always observe the survival time. Also, with no censoring $U_i=T_i$ and hence $I(U_i\le t)=I(T_i\le t)$.

But I do not understand *why does Kaplan-Meier estimator for the censoring distribution, $\hat S(U_i)$, which appears in the above first equation vanish in the second equation with no censoring?*

Comment: Recall, KM and most survival methods are based on unique failure times, as the informativeness for survival comes from failures only -- not censored.   Also, each object (patient, mouse, etc) contributes to a failure variable (0-censored, 1-failed) and a time variable [$t$=time to failure or time to censoring (end of study or loss to follow-up)].   If you look at the product limit variant of KM, there's not a censoring time and a failure time, but rather bin counts for failures as a function of time interval.

Comment: Can you give a source to where you found this expression? I am not following the meaning of $R$ and $Z$. In Fine/Gray JASA 1999 Proportional Hazards Model for the Subdistribution of a Competing Risk, $Z$ is the modeled effect of covariates and $R$ is a cause-specific indicator matrix. You might want to start with a simpler case.

Answer (score 1):

The Kaplan-Meier Curve does not disappear when there is complete data.  The true survival function is S(t)=1-F(t).  The Kaplan-Meier is also called the product limit estimator.  If you look it up in wikipedia you will find the case of complete data and the form of the KM curve as a product.

Comment: Does it mean the second equation of the post  inaccurate?

Comment: There should only be one censoring time C in the study and that is the time you stop to finalize the result.  In the complete data case all event times are less than C.  So the indicator functions should all equal 1.

Comment: I now see how the substitutions  for the complete case that you exhibit in equation 2 loses the survivor function in the denominator but I don't know what the indicator functions R_i and Z_i represent.  Also what does the probability p refer to?

Comment: Were you able to find the formula for the KM estimator in wikipedia?

Comment: Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan-Meier-estimator .

Comment: In the formula of Kaplan-Meier Estimator :the censored individuals are excluded from the denominator of ‘at risk’ individuals at the point when they are censored, however, are included at each preceding point. They are not included in numerator at any point.   (continuing)

Comment: (continuation) But  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator#Basic_concepts also has a sentence that `When no truncation or censoring occurs, the Kaplan–Meier curve is the complement of the empirical distribution function.` Then why does $\hat S(t)$ disapper from the second equation of the post instead of reducing to empirical distribution function?